# Site travando em páginas especificas

Tags: jquery

Tenho poucas funções nesse site, mas acredito que algum jQuery está fazendo a seguinte [página](http://www.congressoconsulfarma.com/Web/cursos/09) travar.

Os scripts, basicamente são:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.contato').hide();
    });

    function mostrar(contato) {
        $('#' + contato).slideToggle();
    }
</script>


<script>
var num = 50; // tanto de scroll que vai precisar para a barra ficar fixa.
$('.navbar-fixed-top').css('top', 150);
$('.ajusteMenu').css('margin-top', 55)
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('top', 20);
    } else {
        //Quando o menu ficar fixo
        $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('top', 150);
    }
});
</script>
```

O que pode estar gerando esse travamento? Até mesmo o inspecionar elemento demora para abrir.

Comment: Você tem o link do site?

Comment: @MoisesGama está ali no link "página". Mas para facilitar: http://www.congressoconsulfarma.com/Web/cursos/09

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apesar de todos os comentários válidos a respeito da forma com quem o site foi desenvolvido, o problema não era esse.

O site havia sofrido um SQL Injection.

Answer (score 5):

Realmente seu site esta mal desenvolvido, faltam abrir e fecharr tags, colocar as coisas nos lugares certos e o erro não tem nada a ver com jquery, tem a ver com boas práticas de desenvolvimento que você não esta seguindo.

Avaliei seu site com esta incrível ferramenta do google ([PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)) , de 0 a 100, o google da nota 9 (mobile) e 11 (desktop) para esta pagina em questão, que você colocou o link ai, isso é horrível para o usuário pois gasta muita banda da internet dele.

Faça algumas coisas básicas:

1. Coloque os scripts e jquerys no final da pagina, antes de .
2. Utilize o minimo possivel de scripts jquery, ou coloque todos eles em um unico arquivo minificado e inclua-os na pagina.
3. Comprima seus scripts e se possível o html.
4. Trabalhe as imagens, estão pesadas demais.
5. veja com o F12 as coisas que estão faltando na pagina, isso atrasa o carregamento do site,ja que até ele ver que não existem, ele continua chamando elas, como o none.js, icon e mais coisas em sua pagina.

[image: PageSpeed Insights]

Você chama 02 vezes os mesmos scripts e nenhum é `.min` chama todos sem compactação, isso não é bom, note que `bootstrap.js` é chamado 02 vezes, só nesta pagina.

```
<script src="/Content/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="/Content/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/css/business-casual.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/css/quadradoCursos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/css/socialIcons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/css/palestrantes.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/js/bootstrap.js" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Por favor, reveja todo o código e abra e feche as tags corretamente, utilize arquivos .min do jquery e bootstrap e explore mais o potencial do bootstrap que deixara seu site leve e com excelente usabilidade!

Comment: não precisa bater tanto no menino. Eu ia responde mas sua resposta está ótima, só esqueceu de falar da semântica do código, o a `tag` `body` e `html` não foram abertas, o `footer` estão fora do fechamento do `body` (que nem sei porque está fechando se não está abrindo onde deveria) e todo o resto. Se fosse validar no W3C jessuis.

Comment: @MoisesGama desculpe, acho que peguei pesado, não tive a intenção de chatear ninguém, mas a gente que desenvolve pega paixão pela coisa, que da até raiva (do código e não da pessoa) quando vemos algo assim.

Comment: sei como é sou igual, mas pelo visto ele está começando e ser desmotivado é muito ruim. Mas na boa entendo como se sente. Abs.

Comment: @MoisesGama vc esta certo, vou editara resposta!

Comment: Desconhecia essa ferramenta do Google vou até adicionar nos favoritos :)

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Ela é tão F0d4 que até lhe da os arquivos compactados para você usar caso ache necessário, não me vejo sem esta ferramenta kkkkkkk E tem uma extensão dela para o Chrome tbm que faz o mesmo trampo e tem o mesmo nome.

Comment: Agradeço a critica de todos. Não, não estou começando e essa aplicação não é minha, eu estou dando manutenção.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do Paulo Roberto está impecável; você deve dar +1, aceitá-la e seguir os conselhos dela.

Tendo dito isso, parte do problema (que o PageSpeed Insights não tem como pegar porque ele não faz OCR) é que você está usando imagens pra representar o que é, fundamentalmente, texto. Você deveria fortemente cogitar a possibilidade de colocar essas imagens como texto na página: assim você reduz o tamanho da sua página e não precisa repetir o conteúdo da imagem no `alt="…"` só pro Google te indexar.

Se o seu cliente fizer questão de uma fonte bonitinha no banner de cada curso, você pode usar uma webfont — [Typekit](http://www.typekit.com/), [Fonts.com](http://www.fonts.com/) têm várias opções a preços acessíveis, e se o cliente não liberar a verba, você pode escolher uma fonte do [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts).